# Linux overheats on Macbook Pro 12,1 (Early 2015), but not on Asus laptop

Tags: linux-mint, macintosh, temperature

I recently bought a Macbook Pro 13" Early 2015. I was successful in installing Linux Mint 18.1 Sarah and everything worked fine but the Macbook Pro started overheating. Idle CPU temperature was around 67-70 degrees Celsius. I tried running a simple python script which printed numbers from 0 to 1 million and saw the temperatures hovering at around 90 degrees Celsius which in my opinion is very hot for a simple program.

I thought it has something to do with Linux Mint and tried installing Ubuntu 16.04 which is the base for Linux Mint and still had the same heat issues. I tried Fedora and RHEL, same heat issues.

I have an Asus ROG gaming laptop which is running Windows and Linux Mint on dual boot and Linux Mint runs around 70 degrees even under heavy load.

I installed macfanctld and it does nothing except run fast for like 10 seconds after boot and then nothing.

My question is, why does Linux run so hot on Apple hardware which has an Intel i5 processor with lower TDP than the Intel i7 on the Asus which has higher TDP rating? I really would love to use Linux on the Macbook Pro without the heat issues.

**[Edit]**
This is my output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
    Kernel driver in use: i915`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest cause of overheating on the MacBook Pro 13 inch Early 2015 that I have found when using Linux Mint is any kind of Chromium browser.

To get this problem under control make sure you disable "Use Hardware Acceleration When Available" in your Chromium browser.

The CPU in the laptop is decent, but the GPU is pretty underpowered which I believe is the cause of the overheating.